# date() function giving me the wrong time even after changing timezone using date_default_timezone_set()

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have set the default timezone in the constructor but the date() is still giving me the wrong time...

```
$time = 'Etc/GMT-4';
date_default_timezone_set($time);
```

and

```
date('g:iA. M j, Y') . ' in ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '.';
```

is giving

```
7:00AM. Mar 13, 2014 in Etc/GMT-4.
```

instead of

```
11:00AM. Mar 12, 2014 in Etc/GMT-4.
```

in addition to all the confusion

`now()` and `time()` are giving different outputs...

Comment: now()? What's now()? Are you running this on your own local machine, or on a remote server?

Comment: I'm running on my local machine. And I think now() is a mysql function, not too sure, but for some reason they would output the same things.

Comment: Is 'Etc/GMT-4' a valid timezone? PHP has a [list of supported timezone strings](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: Yeah it is, but it's okay I'm changing the signup form so that ill get a specific supported timezone. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is a PHP behavior or a bug, however we want to call it:

> For some reason the Etc/GMT timezones implement the GMT offset the "wrong way"

(source: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34710)

So, if you are in GMT-4 you have to use

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+4');
```

Regards